# How to test Python wheels on CI

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, python-wheel

I'm am running my tests on Azure Pipelines (but the same thing applies to Travis and Appveyor). I have a Python package, let's call it `calculator` which contains cython extensions. When I push to my repository, the CI servers clone my package and install it using `python setup.py develop`, then run `pytest` to run the tests. Running `python setup.py develop` builds the extensions inplace, so the shared objects are in the actual directory. So when my unittests run `import calculator`, the cwd is the source directory, so the actual copies of the python scripts are used, which contain the shared object files right there, so everything works fine.

Now, I want to replace `python setup.py develop` with `python setup.py install`. Now, the extensions are no longer built in the current source directory, but are packaged and installed into the python path. However, when pytest is called after installation, python can still find the `calculator` module in the working directory, and (I guess) ignores the properly installed `calculator` module. And because the extensions weren't built inplace, the tests fails saying the extension module is not found.

The reason I want to do this is because I also have wheels set up to be built on the CI servers. When I build a wheel, I would also like to make sure nothing went wrong and install that wheel and run tests on it. Similarily to `python setup.py install`, I suppose the `calcualtor` module in the working directory takes precedence over my installed wheel, and results in extension import errors.

How do people typically deal with this?

Comment: How does your package-layout looks like? You could use src-layout (*.so's aren't in the path) + `pip install -e` (instead of `python setup.py develop`),  so `pip -uninstall  <package name>` works and then `pip install`.

Comment: To keep with the running example, my package folder contains a `calculator` module and tests in a separate folder; I don't include tests in the wheels or sdists. Also, the wheels are built in a separate job, so the package is never actually installed until the wheel is built, and then it's installed from the wheel. But because the working directory is the calculator folder, it's preppended to `sys.path` and takes precedence over the installed wheel.

Comment: So why not use src-layout? see also recomendation https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules

Comment: That actually addresses my problem perfectly. Thanks! However, it seems to me that if I move over to this layout, it might be a bit more tedious to develop the package, since then I'll have to install the package to test any changes, and if I use tox, that might take a long time. Any tips on that?

Comment: @Pavlin - it will still work fine as long as you 1. Use a virtualenv, 2. Have installed the package using `pip install -e .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read up quite a bit on this since posting this question and the problem stems from the fact that Python automatically prepends the working directory to `sys.path`. Since CI servers have their working path set to the source directory, the actual source files take precedence over the installed library. There are two solutions:

1. We can switch the package over to a `src` layout, which just means renaming the typical convention of my calculator package containing source files from `calculator` to `src`. This requires that setup is then properly adjusted, and that the `src` directory contains a single directory called `calculator`. This, in my opinion, is ugly, so I went with the much simpler option
2. simply remove or rename the source directory on the CI server, so that the package can't be found in the working directory. In my specific case, I just ran `mv calculator src` before running my tests.